# How to impose a condition creating a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I want to create a matrix with all the possible combinations of 10 numbers between 0 and 100, with intervals of 5, that its sum be equal to 100. I mean something like this:

```
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 90; 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 20 0;...)
```

I use "allcomb.m" to create something like all the possible numbers that are between 0 and 100, with intervals of 5. However, this matrix is so big, and that implies that Matlab doesn't create it. I was thinking that, if I have that matrix, I could reduce it using a condition but this is impossible because I never get the matrix. 
So, the question is how I can modify the  allcomb's code with the condition in the same code or maybe, and better, another way to create the matrix that I purpose.

Comment: I don't know how you do it in matlab, but in python you'd use a generator, e.g. an object that creates elements of a sequence only when you ask for the next one, not all at once. I imagine in this case a similar thing would need to happen

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that even the result matrix is very large - to be precise, it has 10,015,005 rows and ten columns, and (if stored as a double) takes up about 1GB of space. On my machine it takes about ten minutes to compute. Nevertheless, it is computable, and the following function computes it.

```
function w = allconstrainedcombinations(n,k)
    if n == 1
        w = k;
    else
        t = nchoosek(n+k-1,k);  # Total number of rows
        w = zeros(t,n);         # Pre-allocate
        r = 1;                  # Current row
        for v = 0:k
            u = allconstrainedcombinations(n-1,k-v);
            m = size(u,1);
            w(r:r+m-1,1) = v;
            w(r:r+m-1,2:end) = u;
            r = r + m;
        end
    end
end
```

To get the result you want, you should call

```
>> x = allconstrainedcombinations(10,20) * 5;
```

Here's the result for a small example:

```
>> allconstrainedcombinations(3,2)
ans =
     0     0     2
     0     1     1
     0     2     0
     1     0     1
     1     1     0
     2     0     0
```

Comment: I'm not even going to try to confirm (or refute) your code or your computations, but +1 for dedicating so much time and effort to answering a stranger's question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the compliment, but the truth is that I wrote this function about a year ago for one of my own applications, so all I did for this answer is clean up the code, rename it and check that it worked with the OP's input.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris. As Mark says, it's remarkable that you dedicate time to my question, or just share your code.